# can sign derived wallet transactions with main's wallet private key of seed phrase?

Tags: go-ethereum, bitcoin, hd-wallets

I would like to sign a transaction from a wallet which is derived from a seed, and sign it, with it's parent first address and private key derived from the seed, can I sign any tx of any derived wallet address after the first's wallet?

if so, can I do it the same for bitcoin?
 thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not derivate wallet from a ethereum seed and sign every wallet derivated with it's fist or parent as you mention, every derivate wallet must be signed with it's own private key.

on bitcoin is another history I could say it is possible because of inputs and outputs called utxo

Regards.